# show all results on VLOOKUP

Tags: google-sheets

On Google sheets I wish to correlate data from a column, every time its adjacent column has a certain attribute.

For example, Imagine I have a list of pupils and the language that they are studying. In column A is the name of the pupil and in column B is the language:

```
NAME           |   LANGUAGE
---------------------------------------------------
John           |   French
James          |   Spanish
Stephen        |   Spanish
Simon          |   German
Mark           |   French
Luke           |   German
Robert         |   French
```

I want to generate a new sheet showing the name of each language, with the names of the people who study it in the adjacent columns. It would look something like this:

```
LANGUAGE       |   NAMES
---------------------------------------------------
French         |   John     |  Mark     |   Robert
German         |   Simon    |  Luke     |  
Spanish        |   James    |  Stephen  |
```

I have tried to achieve this with `VLOOKUP` however this only returns the first value encountered for each language, rather than all the values.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming 'French' is in cell A2 of Sheet2, in B2 you could try something like

```
=transpose(filter(Sheet1!$A$2:$A; Sheet1!$B$2:$B=$A2))
```

and fill down.

(change ranges to suit).

Answer (score 2):

Try QUERY which is so powerful with transpose added too:

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(Sheet1!A2:ZZ, "SELECT A WHERE B = '"French"'"))
```